# Can I do anything to recover a file that I did not save?

Tags: microsoft-word-2011

I meant to discard one document, but instead discarded a document I needed. When the computer asked me if I wanted to save, I clicked "do not save". Is there any way I can look for the file?

I have a MaC OSX, Microsoft Word 2011

Thanks for the help

Comment: Had you saved the document you wanted before you accidentally didn't save it?? If you had, then autosave might have saved it, but if you didn't, then I'm afraid Wutnaut's answer may be correct - I hope someone proves me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Sorry.

By default Word does save some auto recovery data in case it crashes, but by clicking "Discard" it will have deleted it.

You might be able to use a file recovery program (asking us what recovery program to use would be off-topic for the site) and/or try searching in the following place:

Finder => Go => Library => Application Support => Microsoft Office => Office 2011 AutoRecovery
(This was taken from [this Apple support page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4278535))

Comment: The answer minimum length limit is there for a reason: to encourage you to not just post a single-line or even single-sentence answer, but actually elaborate on it, explain why the short answer is correct, etc etc. There's nothing wrong with including a short summary, but details, background and explanation make such answers much more useful. For an example illustrating how this can be done, [here's an answer by me](http://superuser.com/a/743784/53590) that uses that exact technique. (Admittedly not terribly highly voted, but the question hasn't seen much activity to begin with either.)

Comment: Valid point @MichaelKjörling. Would you like to help me elaborate my answer? Maybe I could have said that "this is what the 'Save' feature is for". I was too hastey to answer.

Comment: I don't have the specific knowledge to tell what the answer to this question should be, so no, I cannot really help you. If I knew, I'd post an answer of my own.