# Can ionice reduce wear and tear on hard disks?

Tags: rsync, find, io, nice

Without knowing how ionice works functionally, I was wondering if ionice more smartly batches disk I/O operations for more efficient physical movement (spinning disks specifically).

I run a lot of content indexing (grep, tee) and transfer (rsync) operations in cron jobs so was wondering if I could instantly make them less damaging.

Comment: Are you confident that your current use-case is indeed "_damaging_", and not just impacting performance negatively?

Comment: Define "damaging".

Comment: Does anyone have any data that says drive access adds more wear and tear that just keeping the drive spinning? I've always been under the (possibly incorrect) understanding that the extra wear from accessing the drive is negligible compared to simply keeping it spinning.

Comment: Michael, I guess the concern of Sridhar Sarnobat is speed. I share your opinion.
There is one other issue: Aggressive energy-saving schemes which involved head parking created wear. There is an issue with disks manufactured with Western Digital but if I remember correctly the problem applied to Seagate as well. They corrected their firmware settings and deleted the option to set the parking time for end-users. I discovered that when trying to have the disk run at least 15 minutes, I did not want earlier parking.

Comment: I'm not interested in speed, these are cron jobs that do not impact my real-time interaction with the machine (a personal file server). Just I don't want to risk losing my data (I guess the tags I used are misleading).

Answer (score -1):

If you have a physical disk, the disk is constantly spinning at the same speed. ionice might give one process priority on disk access, but the amount of random reads and writes depend on the specific operation you are doing. The wear of a HDD is mostly constant, it doesn't really matter what you do while it's active. To make a HDD last many years you just have to use it less. SSDs wear down from write cycles. HDDs don't really mind how much you write or read from them, they keep spinning until they break from external impact like falling, over voltage or something else. It's not likely for your disk to stop working because the platters and drive heads moved so much they fall apart.

It is possible for ionice to reduce wear and tear on disks. The impact is extremely small though.
The biggest improvement in wear of the disk would be if it makes the read write operations finish faster, so you're having disk activity for a shorter time period.
Either way, there is no need to worry about HDD activity, just take care of your HDD and don't drop it or get it wet.

Comment: "It is possible for ionice to reduce wear and tear on disks. The impact is extremely small though." So there is no "reduced wear" at all? Please give an example how ionice reduces "wear and tear".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's good enough for me. It wasn't me who downvoted.

Comment: For anyone who cares, most of my HDD disks much longer than the web literature that says they last between 3 and 5 years (I've mostly been a Western Digital consumer).

Answer (score -1):

Any advanced OS will re-order pending disk writes in what it decides is the optimal order,
which may include disk order among other parameters.
This is one of the functions of disk caches and disk schedulers.

Any such OS will keep the written data in the cache and only write it out
according to its I/O scheduling parameters.
The writes will be issued in optimal order, so not just by
chronological write-times.

It's not advisable to change any of the disk scheduling parameters
of the OS. The OS algorithms are surely better than anything you
could invent, crafted by operating-system research over the last
decades.

What I'm trying to say is that disk writes are already as optimized
as they can be in view of the hardware and the file-system : Trust
your OS.

Note that many disks have their own on-board disk caches and will
optimize writes even further, using parameters that are perhaps
not communicated to the OS.

`ionice` will not make any discernible difference, except to make
your data have less priority than that of other running jobs.
The OS scheduler will handle your write operations to the cache
behind those of other programs.
Once the data is in the memory cache, ionice has no more effect and your data writing to the disk will be handled the same as any other.

Comment: This is nonsense: "Any good OS will re-order concurrent disk accesses by disk order in any case, which is why disk caches were created."

Comment: @r2d3: What ????? You can't be serious.

Comment: What do you mean by "by disk order"? I doubt my Debian knows the exact physical layout of heads, platters, remapped sectors and so in my HDDs. In the days of CHS OSs could and should know some of these, but nowadays everything uses LBA. I doubt my Debian, when casting writes, can know the "optimal order, which takes into account their position on the disk". Each disk itself must know its layout, so it can optimize this; but an OS? Are you sure an OS can do this? OTOH you wrote "any good OS will", so maybe you are right but our OSs are just not the good ones. :)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Nowadays there are only good OS (except perhaps DOS). The OS knows the disk layout, cylinders and sectors (even if just a fiction for SSD) and knows the block address to which it's writing to. So, yes, an OS can do that, and the disk firmware surely can do that even better. Power cuts can cause missing file-blocks, and it's not always the last blocks in the file that are missing, exactly because of the reason that the order of block-writes was optimized.

Comment: @r2d3: Linear disk addresses can also be sorted. Whichever addressing mode is used, an order exists.

Comment: @harrymc But the order of LBA does not have to have anything to do with the physical layout. I think the following is right: "[The physical drive is then free to translate this to whatever internal geometry it uses, by whatever means it chooses to use](https://superuser.com/a/743784/432690)". The OS may assume that writing to sequential LBA numbers is close to optimal (it often is), but it cannot know it's *the* optimal order.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: The full sentence was "When the operating system's disk driver wants some amount of data, it issues a read request for sector number N, or the interval sector numbers M through N. The physical drive is then free to translate this to whatever internal geometry it uses, by whatever means it chooses to use". Some disk drivers on the OS side may still believe in cylinders and sectors, because it's easier and because some low-level disk API requests still use these values as parameters, even if they are fiction. Any OS contains legacy code.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: An I/O scheduler that uses cache timestamps as its only parameter for transmitting write requests to the disk is too simplistic. HDD OS and disk firmware I/O should at least be optimized for minimizing head movements.

Comment: @harrymc The OS assumes that sequential access to LBA numbers is better than non-sequential; and that jumping back and forth between low LBA numbers and high LBA numbers is worse than staying in one "neighborhood". These are sane assumptions, almost always true. Following them gives the OS an order close to the optimal, but not necessarily *the* optimal order. It wasn't clear what you meant by "by disk order". If LBA then fine (although it should be made clear); but from your comments I see you mean CHS, while nowadays even if the OS "thinks" it knows CHS, it's just legacy, not reality.

Comment: @harrymc Two of my modern 3.5" HDDs report 64 heads; another one is 2.5" (although thicker than the standard) and it reports 255 heads. I think the real number of heads is about 10 or less (like here: [Western Digital RED 6TB WD60EFRX Hard Drive TEARDOWN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnBPLuw-LnY&t=1054s)). No modern OS shall optimize writes for the alleged 64 or 255 heads, these numbers are bogus. Old software may try to use the numbers, but it cannot really optimize anything this way, because the numbers do not match the reality.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Best disk optimizations are when the fictional HDD values are as close to reality as possible. I agree that some optimizations are useless today, but that doesn't mean that are not still being done, because the OS cannot fully know the nature of the disk.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I finally don't understand what we're arguing about. (1) Is there an order when writing from cache to disk? Of course there is. (2) Is disk position a parameter? Opinions may vary. (3) Are cache-write rules dependent on disk-type? No indication that the Windows cache is divided to sub-caches by target-type. (4) Just to say that I dissected a few years ago a fast file-copier to understand its speed, and found that it used low-level API to workaround the Windows cache, hence my conclusion that Windows cache algorithms may not fit modern disks, kind of one-size-fits-all.

Comment: Wait… Your words: "hence my conclusion that Windows cache algorithms may not fit modern disks"; but earlier "Any good OS will re-order pending disk writes in optimal order, which includes disk order among other parameters. This is one of the functions of disk caches and disk schedulers" and "Nowadays there are only good OS (except perhaps DOS)". How can cache algorithms not fit modern disks and still produce writes in *optimal order*? And then "disks […] will optimize writes even further". If something can be optimized further then it's not yet optimal. Sorry, you stack nonsense now.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: No, I said that an OS does that, not that it does it well. Perhaps "good OS" should have been "advanced OS". For Windows, nothing would surprise me, seeing the performance of the disk cache. You're misunderstanding my words, so I give up. My Windows experience contradicts people's logic, but pure logic is not enough where legacy code is involved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure which of the 2 to mark as correct.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat: I have added some small text at the end of my answer. Choose the answer that best answered your question. Note that I don't think that ionice can make a difference as regarding disk wear.